# How to show a HTMLTag inside <CardHeader> Material UI Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI version 4.9.5 and React version 16.13.
Inside CardHeader tag i need to show 2 buttons. I tried placing buttons inside CardHeader tag but they dont show up. I placed the buttons inside title attribute of CardHeader but it shows buttons html code.
How to show HTML tag inside the CardHeader tag?

This is the part of code:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Card elevation={2} >
        <CardHeader title= 'New Clin' className = {classes.cardHeaderClass}></CardHeader>
         <CardContent className={classes.formContainer} >
          <Divider className={classes.divider} />
          <Grid container>
```

Comment: I just updated my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like in material ui card [example](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#complex-interaction), you need to add your button in action cardHeader props like for example:

```
 <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
        subheader="September 14, 2016"
      />
```